# Matlab filter returns Nan values

Tags: matlab, filtering

I'm trying to create a filter with manipulated samples, but i got i filter whom values are Nan, therefore my signal is "killed"

```
function x_quantizzato = Quantizzazione_forma_diretta(NUM, DEN, y)
l_num=length(NUM);
l_den=length(DEN);
numeratore=zeros(1,length(NUM));
denominatore=zeros(1,length(DEN));


for i=1:l_num
numeratore(i) = quantizzatore(NUM(i));

end

for i=1:l_den
denominatore(i)=quantizzatore(DEN(i));

end

Q_quant=filter(numeratore, denominatore, y);
Q_quant
x_quantizzato = Q_quant(1:11:end);

%soundsc(x_quantizzato);

return;
```

after the second end, numeratore = 0.0039   -0.0352    0.1133   -0.2148    0.2617   -0.2148    0.1133   -0.0352    0.0039
  and denominatore = 1.0000   -7.4375   24.5000  -46.0000   54.0000  -41.0000   19.2500   -5.2500    0.6250

Comment: What is "quantizzatore"?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is unstable, make sure your filter is stable, i.e. the impulse response decays as time increases, before applying the filter